# Transpose with row condition

Tags: text-formatting

Need help in formatting below test data in unix.

Sample data:

```
Dan serv1 p1
Dan serv2 p2
Dan serv3 p3 
Dus serv2 p1
Dus serv3 p2
Dus Serv5 p3 
Tes serv3 p1
Tes serv5 p3
```

Needed format:

```
Name p1    p2    p3
Dan serv1 serv2 serv3
Dus serv2 serv3 serv5
TEs serv3       Serv5
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome! This is very unclear, and also, you don't show any own attempt or explain where you're stuck. I'm not even sure we *can* help you, given we don't know where you need help, and certainly are not in the business of doing your work :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is data format which we are trying to get sorted for a project in UNIX and the current awk samples didnt provide me in the fomrat required. Thats why asked for help

Answer (score 0):

```bash
mlr --n2p \
    label Name,Server,Prio then \
    reshape -s Prio,Server then \
    unsparsify  file
```

Output:

```
Name p1    p2    p3
Dan  serv1 serv2 serv3
Dus  serv2 serv3 Serv5
Tes  serv3 -     serv5
```

This uses [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) (`mlr`) to first label the three fields in the input as `Name`, `Server`, and `Prio`, in this order (I have no clue whether these labels make sense, but they are nicer to work with than field numbers).  After labelling, the data is reshaped to get new records for each `Name`.  Each new record has a `Name` field followed by the `Prio` fields.  The value for each `Prio` field is the `Server` value.

The final `unsparsify` operation creates empty fields for records that lack values for some fields (this adds the `-` that you see in the output).

The `--n2p` option is a shorthand for `--inidx` (indexed input fields) followed by `--opprint` (pretty-printed output).  You could also try `--n2t` to get tab-delimited output, or `--n2c` to get CSV.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ id=substr($NF,2); nf=nf<id?id:nf; serv[$1, id]= $2 }
END  { for (x in serv){
           split(x, tmp, SUBSEP)
           if(x in serv){
               printf ("%s", tmp[1])
               for (i=1; i<=nf; i++){
                   printf ("%s", OFS "[" serv[tmp[1], i] "]")
                   delete serv[tmp[1], i]
               }
               print ""
           }
       }
}' infile
```

Output:

```
Dan [serv1] [serv2] [serv3]
Dus [serv2] [serv3] [Serv5]
Tes [serv3] [] [serv5]
```